# How to initialize class object with array reference passed as a template argument to constructor in C++ 17 using braced initializator?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a template class and want to pass a reference to an array in its constructor, using braced initializator.

```
template<typename T, size_t ar_sz> class Test_class {
    // Thats incorrect
    /*
    T t;
    size_t size;
    */
    
    // Thats correct?
    T array[ar_sz];
public:

    Test_class(const T (&array)[ar_sz]) {
    }

};

int main() {
  
    constexpr size_t array_sz = 1;
    int ar_i[array_sz]{ 1 };

    Test_class test_ar{ ar_i };

}
```

So how to properly do that?

EDIT:

I want to add that i need to pass `L"test"` to a constructor, which is a `const wchar_t[5]`, so this task cant be resolved using `std::array<>`

Comment: the member is `T`, the parameter to the constructor is reference to array of `T`

Comment: use `::std::array` if you want to copy-initialize a member array

Comment: you need to decide: Is `T` the element type ? or is it the type of the array? And in either case you cannot copy c-arrays like this

Comment: "*using braced initializator*" Don't. Braced-init-lists are *not* a quick way to create arrays. They are tools for initializing an object. That's it. They can initialize arrays, but only *directly*.

Comment: An `int` has no way of being constructed from an array of `int`.  You have not mentioned what you want this code to do - only that it will not compile.

Comment: when you ask "how to properly do that?", what exactly is "that" which you are trying to achieve? Your `Test_class` isnt doing something that an `std::array` cannot do. Even if you need the array as member you can use `std::array` and all issues are gone

Comment: i cant use std::array, because in real scenario i pass wchar_t[] array like `test_ar{L"test"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler deduces `T = int` and `ar_sz = 1`. In your template, declaration `T t;` means the same as `int t;`. You don't want this! You want `T t[ar_sz];`. BTW to reduce confusion, use array size greater than 1.

Another problem is (as other people noted): you can't initialize an array using another array. You need explicit copying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, size_t size> 
struct Test
{
public:
    T m_values[size]; // array, not element (you could also use std::array)

    Test(const T (&values)[size])
    {
        std::copy(values, values + size, m_values); // explicit copying (you could also use memcpy)
    }

    const auto& values() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Test test("meh");

    std::cout << test.values()[1] << '\n';
    std::cout << test.values()[2] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if i pass anything but array this wont work. I need generic template constructor that can take `int`, or `int[]`, without template specialization.

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify it. Or ask a different question. If what you want to ask is significantly different from what you actually asked, better start a new question (i.e. don't invalidate existing answers).

Comment: i edited my question a little bit, but the main task remained the same, and i think your answer sheds some light to my problem. At least i better understand now where i made a mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::array as already suggested, also when initializing you need an extra pair of {} to pass the values.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t ar_sz> 
class Test_class 
{
public:
    Test_class(const std::array<T,ar_sz>& values) : 
        m_values{ values } 
    {
    }

    const auto& values() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

private:
    std::array<T, ar_sz> m_values;

};

int main() 
{
    std::array values{ 1,2,3 };
    Test_class test_ar{ values };     

    std::cout << test_ar.values()[2];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: as i said in the question, i need a braced initialization without template specification.

Comment: Not sure why that is a problem, but if you want the compiler to deduce more you can use these too`

Comment: in real life scenario a use `test_ar{L"test"}` , and `L"test"` is `const wchar_t[5]` and not `std::array`

Comment: @hgrev ¿Are you aware that C-style arrays are not copyable? If you are going to use them as inputs then you'll need to add a loop to copy items.

Comment: Can i pass by reference and not copy them? At least thats what i am trying to do

Comment: @hgrev You've implemented pass by reference correctly. The error in the question is caused by incorrect member initializaiton.

Comment: Then what is the problem with the code sample? I pass C-array in template constructor by reference, but the object doesnt instantiate

Comment: Then there is no way to initialize array reference in constructor before its body.

Comment: @hgrev Just delete `T t; size_t size;` and `: t{ array }, size{ ar_sz }` and it will compile. Or just remove `t{ array }, `

Comment: Yes but it wont initialize member.

Comment: @hgrev Yes, and the problem with your code is that you are trying to initialize a member with object of incompatible type.